# Four-divergence of the wedge product

Tags: special-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

I have maybe simple question, but I cannot find it anywhere in the internet.

When I calculate four-divergence on tensor, being wedge product, do I calculate it the way A or B?

$$ 
\partial_{\alpha} \, \,(X^{\alpha} \wedge Y^{\beta}) =
$$

A) $$ = (\partial_{\alpha} X^{\alpha}) Y^{\beta} -  (\partial_{\alpha} Y^{\alpha}) X^{\beta} $$

or

B) $$ = (\partial_{\alpha} X^{\alpha}) Y^{\beta} + X^{\alpha}.(\partial_{\alpha}Y^{\beta}) -  (\partial_{\alpha} Y^{\alpha}) X^{\beta} -  Y^{\alpha}.(\partial_{\alpha}X^{\beta}) $$

Comment: Note $\partial_\alpha X^\alpha$ is a scalar (0-form), so you are asking about the wedge product of a 0-form with a 1-form. There's an answer about this here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/651101/. The result is that a wedge product with a 0-form is equivalent to ordinary multiplication.

Comment: I take four-divergence on whole tensor. I added brackets in the equation.

Comment: I'm confused by your notation.  Are you saying that $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf Y$ are vectors and you'd like to compute the divergence of the tensor $\mathbf X\wedge \mathbf Y$?  My interpretation is that $X^\alpha$ and $Y^\beta$ are the *components* of the vectors $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf Y$, in which case the wedge product between them is simply ordinary multiplication.  If you want the $(\alpha,\beta)$ component of the tensor product, then that would be $(\mathbf X\wedge\mathbf Y)^{\alpha\beta} = \frac{1}{2}\left(X^\alpha Y^\beta- X^\beta Y^\alpha\right)$.

Comment: These are four-vectors. I use notation used some times in Special Relativity physics. Here is link with the notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector

Comment: @pog J. Murray is correct; you are abusing notation. $A^\mu$ is not a vector, it is the *components* of a vector. In day-to-day physics language this often gets overlooked, but if you are using a wedge product it matters. I guess what you are looking for is something like $\frac{1}{2}\partial_\alpha\left(X^\alpha Y^\beta - X^\beta Y^\alpha\right)$.

Comment: Ok, let it be :-) What is the result of the divergencr then?

Answer (score 1):

The divergence of a $(2,0)$-tensor $\mathbf T$ is the $(1,0)$-tensor $\mathrm{div}(\mathbf T)$ with components
$$\big[\mathrm{div}(\mathbf T)\big]^\nu = \nabla_\mu T^{\mu \nu}$$

If $\mathbf T = \mathbf X\wedge \mathbf Y$ where $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf Y$ are vectors, then $T^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}(X^\mu Y^\nu - X^\nu Y^\mu)$.  From there, assuming you are using Cartesian coordinates in which $\nabla_\mu \rightarrow \partial_\mu$, the rest is just the ordinary application of the product rule.